# Selecting an element with xpath and Selenium use contains

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, contains

i need href website link. But is not. How can I invoke

My html code is this...

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com/blabla/blabla/blabla/blablabla" target="_blank">Çekme İşlemini Onayla</a>
```

My C# code is this...

```
var link = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*/a[contains(.,'Çekme İşlemini Onayla')]")).Text;
```

help pls thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Text` property, you can use `GetAttribute()` method to get an attribute value :

```
var a = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Çekme İşlemini Onayla')]"));
var href = a.GetAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get by

```
string strhref =  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Çekme İşlemini Onayla')]")).GetAttribute("href");;
```

Comment: What does this answer does that the answer given by har07 months earlier does not do?